# How to Use libsimdpp for android?

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk, arm, neon

I am trying to use libsimdpp for android.
But there is no method for it so I can not build project now.
Please help me quickly.
The libsimdpp is open source in https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp/.
Thanks.

Comment: It's a header-only library, like boost, so you just #include the relevant header(s) in your .cpp source files.

Comment: Thanks. But when I used this header files in android ndk, there are many errors.

Comment: You would need to copy and paste the first few errors into your question in order for anyone to help with this.

Comment: You also need to set appropriate compile flags.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply include the library in your source tree and #include into the source files where needed.